# 構造体のフィールドのvecをループさせながら、内容に応じてミュータブルなメソッドを呼び出すときはどのようにすればよいですか？

Tags: rust

最近Rustを始めた初心者ですが、タイトルのような状況でどうすればよいかと考えています。

ある処理を後でまとめて行うためにフィールドの`vec`に処理を`enum`として格納し、まとめて実行するために以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
struct Data {
    data: Vec<u8>,
    operations: Vec<Operation>,
}

enum Operation {
    A(usize),
    B(usize),
    C(usize, usize)
}

impl Data {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        for op in self.operations.iter() {
            match *op {
                Operation::A(x) => self.a(x),  // ここでエラー
                Operation::B(x) => self.b(x),  // ここでエラー
                Operation::C(x, y) => self.c(x, y),  // ここでエラー
            }
        }
    }

    fn a(&mut self, x: usize) {
        // self.dataに対する何らかの操作
        unimplemented!()
    }
    fn b(&mut self, x: usize) {
        // self.dataに対する何らかの操作
        unimplemented!()
    }
    fn c(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) {
        // self.dataに対する何らかの操作
        unimplemented!()
    }

   // operationを追加するメソッドは省略
}
```

しかし、mutableとimmutableの参照が同時には存在できないというエラーが出てしまいます。

> ```
> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
>  --> src/main.rs:20:36
>   |
> 18 |         for op in self.operations.iter() {
>   |                   ----------------------
>   |                   |
>   |                   immutable borrow occurs here
>   |                   immutable borrow later used here
> 19 |             match *op {
> 20 |                 Operation::A(x) => self.a(x),
>   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
> ```

また、評価のために`run`メソッドを何度も呼び出したいと考えているため、`run`メソッド内で`operations`をコピーしてしまうのはオーバーヘッドの問題から避けたいと考えています。

極力オーバーヘッドが小さい方法でこのエラーに対処するなにか良い方法があればご教示いただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a`,`b`,`c`が`data`のみを変更するのであれば,`Data`全体を受け取る代わりに`[u8]`を受け取るように書き換えるのがよいと思います.

```
// DataとOperationの定義はそのまま

impl Data {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        // dataとoperationsの所有権を個別に扱う
        let Self { data, operations } = self;
        for op in operations.iter() {
            match *op {
                Operation::A(x) => Self::a(data, x),
                Operation::B(x) => Self::b(data, x),
                Operation::C(x, y) => Self::c(data, x, y),
            }
        }
    }

    fn a(data: &mut [u8], x: usize) {
        data[x] += 1;
    }
    fn b(data: &mut [u8], x: usize) {
        data[x] += 2;
    }
    fn c(data: &mut [u8], x: usize, y: usize) {
        data[x] += 3;
        data[y] += 4;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data {
        data: vec![0; 6],
        operations: vec![
            Operation::A(1),
            Operation::B(2),
            Operation::C(3, 4),
            Operation::A(5),
        ],
    };

    data.run();
    println!("{:?}", data.data);
    data.run();
    println!("{:?}", data.data);
}
```

**実行結果**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`self`絡みの所有権エラーは構造体を分割すると楽になることがよくあります（[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a44295b1781f76e896ccd918b123129a)）。この例では `data` と `operation` の所有者を分けています。

```rust
enum Operation {
    A(usize),
    B(usize),
    C(usize, usize)
}

struct Dispatcher {
    operations: Vec<Operation>,
}

impl Dispatcher {
    fn run(&mut self, worker: &mut Worker) {
        for op in self.operations.iter() {
            match *op {
                Operation::A(x) => worker.a(x), 
                Operation::B(x) => worker.b(x), 
                Operation::C(x, y) => worker.c(x, y),
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn add(&mut self, op: Operation) {
        self.operations.push(op); 
    }
}

struct Worker {
    data: Vec<u8>
}

impl Worker {
    fn a(&mut self, x: usize) {
        println!("Executing A({}): data[0] = {}", x, self.data[0]);
    }
    fn b(&mut self, x: usize) {
        println!("Executing B({})", x);
    }
    fn c(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) {
        println!("Executing C({}, {})", x, y);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut worker = Worker { data: vec![1, 2, 3] };
    let mut dispatcher = Dispatcher { operations: vec![Operation::A(3), Operation::B(4)] };
    dispatcher.add(Operation::C(5, 6));
    
    dispatcher.run(&mut worker);
}
```

なお、`usize` が `Copy` を実装しているため、それで構成される `Operation` も `Copy` を実装しています。したがって、`match *op` で参照を外すときに`operations`の要素がそれぞれコピーされています（一個ずつではありますが）。